# How to remove the black dot in new product widget on main page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, rwd-theme, widget

I installed the rwd theme and set the new product widget on homepage.
But the list show a black dot each.
How can i remove the dot?[image]
I checked the style.css in skin-> frontend -> rwd -> default -> css.
But I can't find the code.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a `custom.css` and register it to your custom xml file like `local.xml`. Check whether your custom.css is loaded to you home page or not.

The widget that you are using may lack appropriate style. So, try adding something like:

`ul.products-grid li.item{ list-style-type: none !important; }`

to your `custom.css` to get the rid of those bullets.

Comment: Yes, Your reply was helpful. I added the code in the styles.css. The black dot disappear finally. Thank you..

Comment: You are most welcome. I think adding this code is better in your custom css file for code maintainability. happy coding !!